# How to use jQuery to onsubmit and check if the value is 2 - 5 characters?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, character

Let's say I have a text field:

```
Username: <input type="text" id="username" class="required" />
<input type="submit" />
```

and I have some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    user = $("#username");

    user.submit(function() {

    })
})
```

I want to check if the length of the value entered in `username` is between 2 - 5 characters after I submit. If it's not then something happens.

I'm not too sure what I should be inside the `user.submit(function(){})`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First you'll need an actual form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var len = $('#username').val().length;
        if (len < 6 && len > 1) {
            this.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Or in HTML5 you can use the `pattern` attribute (not supported in Safari and IE9-and below):

```html
<!-- Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymdQq/ -->

<form id="myForm">
  Username: <input type="text" id="username" pattern=".{2,5}" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the value of the input field with `user.val()` and the length of the string with `user.val().length`.

That way you can do something like this:

```
if(user.val().length < 2 || user.val().length > 5) {
    console.log('test')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    length = $("#username").val().length;
    if ((length > 2 && length < 5)) {
      $("#output").html("correct, logging in");
    } else {
      $("#output").html("incorrect, must have 3 or 4 chars");
    }
    return (length > 2 && length < 5);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorns/b5Kqs/ -->

<form id="form" mehtod="POST" action="https://www.example.com">
  username: <input type="text" id="username" class="required" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind submit to `form` instead of *input type text* and check its value in submit event. It would be better to assign some id to form and use form id selector to bind submit.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
      username = $('#username').val();
     if(username.length > 1 && username.length < 6)
     {
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try form validation for this kind of verification

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.